# GDAL equivalent to ArcGIS Union?

Tags: python, gdal, polygon, union

I have a single shapefile full of overlapping polygons. The ArcGIS Union tool will generate individual, non-overlapping polygons with that geometry. Is there a way to do this with GDAL/OGR or another Python library that is not made by ESRI?  The ogr.union function in OGR seems to be more like a 'dissolve' in ArcGIS.

Comment: I don't have an answer but you are right that ESRI dissolve means the same as ST_Union in the OGC and ISO standards. Rear more from http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html and also http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8456.

Comment: Have you looked at this OGR cookbook example: https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html#calculate-union-between-two-geometries?

Comment: Intersect the layer with itself and then erase/difference/whatever it's called the result from the original and merge?